# Cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, osx, 64-bits, 32-bits

Estou tentando rodar um código no Linux e estou recebendo essa mensagem:

> Cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Fiz umas pesquisas e isso poderia ser por causa da estrutura do meu pc, mas pelo que eu vejo meu pc tem a estrutura certa pro arquivo que eu quero rodar.

Vejam:

```
File NomeFile
NomeFile: Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 executable

uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 16 23:32:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Se não me engano não é conflito de *bits* não? E se não é isso como eu posso resolver isso?

**Obs**.: O executável que eu estou tentando rodar foi programado primeiramente em Mac e foi passado para o Linux, eu não achei que daria problema já que ambos trabalham com Unix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Essa mensagem indica que o formato do arquivo que você quer executar não é *utilizado* ou *suportado* pelo sistema operacional.

No teu caso, o formato do arquivo é o [`Mach-O`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachORuntime/) que é especifico para o OS *X*.
O formato executável padrão que [o Ubuntu usa](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/elf.5.html#contenttoc3) (e Linux em [geral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)) é o [`ELF`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/elf.5.html#contenttoc0).

Existem algumas ferramentas que prometem auxiliar a conversão, como o [**objconv**](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv) por exemplo.